# Check if specific checkboxes are checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a form with multiple checkboxes like this:

```
<form id="myForm">
   <input type="checkbox" id="first" />
   <input type="checkbox" id="second" />
   <input type="checkbox" id="third" />
</form>
```

I want to do something (i.e. alert box) only when checkbox 1 and 3 are selected.

I know how to target one check box like this:

```
$('#first').click(function () {
    if ($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
        alert("I'm checked!");
    }
});
```

But is there a way to do that for specific multiple checkboxes?

Comment: `if ($('#first').is(':checked') && $('#third').is(':checked')) {`

Comment: @Zainab you want to show the alert when the both checked or just when one of them checked

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki if both are checked, so #first && #third

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the checkbox is checked using `is(':checked')`, you can check the if the both are checked using `&&` sign check example bellow.

Hope this helps.

---

```js
$("#first, #third").click(function () {
  if ($('#first').is(':checked') && $('#third').is(':checked')) 
  {
    alert("Message!");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm">
   <input type="checkbox" id="first" />
   <input type="checkbox" id="second" />
   <input type="checkbox" id="third" />
</form>
```

Comment: You are checking for the input type=checkbox and then using the id selector ? Why the double pain when you can target the id directly ?

Comment: That's not what i meant. You could simply do $("#first, #third").click instead of $('#myForm input[type="checkbox"]').click

Comment: Okay sorry for the misunderstood, and thanks for your intervention (updated my answer).

Comment: Also, since you are already passing the id selector, you could simply do $(this).is(':checked') instead of $('#first').is(':checked') && $('#third').is(':checked') - removes hardcoded references and redundancy.

Comment: I can't since i don't know who is the checked one and i want to check the both in condition.

Comment: Ok. That makes sense. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

This answer works on the premise that you want to when *either* of the specified check-boxes are checked, rather than when they're *both* checked, this can be done with either comma separated selectors:

```
$('#first, #third')
```

Or through the use of a class-name to identify the relevant elements:

```
$('.alertIfSelectedClassName')
```

With the HTML of:

```
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="checkbox" class="alertIfSelectedClassName" id="first" />
  <input type="checkbox" id="second" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="alertIfSelectedClassName" id="third" />
</form>
```

The use of CSS attribute selection,nbased on a shared attribute, such as the name of the `<input>`:

```
$('input[name=alertIfSelectedElementName')
```

HTML:

```
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="checkbox" name="alertIfSelectedElementName" id="first" />
  <input type="checkbox" id="second" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="alertIfSelectedElementName" id="third" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through them:

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input type="checkbox" name="somename" id="first" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="somename" id="second" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="somename" id="third" />
</form>

$('checkbox[name=somename"]').each(function () {
    if ($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
        alert("I'm checked!");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
      $('#first, #third').click(function () {
          var firstChecked = $('#first).prop("checked") == true);
          var thirdChecked = $('#third).prop("checked") == true);
          if (firstChecked  && thirdChecked ) {
             alert("I'm checked!");
          }
       })
```

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/p1zjaw46/

```
var $toCheck = $('#first').add('#third');
$(function () {
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function () {


    if ( $toCheck.filter(':checked').length === $toCheck.length )
      alert('good');
    else
      alert('bad');
  })
});
```

Basically:

1. cache the items you want to check into a var. `$toCheck` in this case.
2. When any are **[changed](https://api.jquery.com/change/)**, do a quick check. You [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) by [`":checked"`](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/), and compare the length of the results of the `filter` to the length of the original set of checkboxes.

If they aren't equal, at least one of the expected boxes aren't checked!

## Why is this answer better than others?

### It's scalable

All you need to do is add new elements to `$toCheck` and the rest is automatic

Comment: How is this more scalable than iterating an array of all the checkboxes?

Comment: It does check all checkboxes but it also iterates over a predefined list of checkboxes who are supposed to be checked. Meaning that if you need 3 boxes instead of 2 to be checked, you simply add it to $toCheck

Answer (score 0):

In order to target a specific elements, try using a `css` class as a selector. Also, include the input `type` so that you don't have any conflict with other elements having the same class.
In order to check if all the required checkboxes are checked or not, you can use `.each()` loop and determine if they are all checked and based on that display the `alert()`.  The following approach avoids any hardcoding and `multiple if` checks.

```
$("input:checkbox.test").click(function()
{
    var allchecked = true;
    $("input:checkbox.test").each(function(){
        if(!$(this).is(":checked")) 
           allchecked = false;         
    });

    if(allchecked)
      alert("Im checked");
});
```

Working example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/fy1asfws/34/